# Building OpenWRT packages on Apple M1 not selecting ARM

Tags: router, openwrt, apple-m1

When trying to build the openWRT package on M1 cpu, cannot determine bitness.

```
checking whether to install ,  and ... yes
checking for working const... yes
checking for off_t... yes
checking for size_t... yes
checking size of short... 0
checking size of int... 0
checking size of long... 0
checking size of long long... 0
checking size of __int64... 0
checking for 64-bit integer... no
checking for 32-bit integer... no
configure: error: neither int nor long is 32-bit
make[2]: *** [/Volumes/OpenWrt/openwrt/build_dir/host/libelf-0.8.13/.configured] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/Volumes/OpenWrt/openwrt/tools/libelf'
time: tools/libelf/compile#0.36#0.35#0.97
make[1]: *** [tools/libelf/compile] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/Volumes/OpenWrt/openwrt'
make: *** [tools/install] Error 2
```

Comment: Have you tried asking in the openwrt forums? I'm interested in a build as well. Nevermind, I see you've asked: https://forum.openwrt.org/t/building-packages-on-apple-m1-cpu/95730

Any progress?